# How can I use a variable value for class name when using makeStyles?

Tags: reactjs, makestyles

In my React app, I have a component which takes in some data.  Depending on the value of that data, I want to show the component with a different coloured background.

The styles are defined as:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  class1: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  class2: {
    backgroundColor: "pink",
  },
}));
```

The component is:

```
const MyBox = ({ data }) => {
  let classes = useStyles();

  let innerClassName;

  if (data.value) {
    innerClassName = "class1";
  } else {
    innerClassName = "class2";
  }

  return (
    <div className={innerClassName}>
Content goes here
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyBox;
```

However, this gives the component a class of "class1" or "class2", which doesn't get picked up by makeStyles.  I also tried `<div className={classes.innerClassName}>` but then it looks for a class called 'innerClassName' which obviously it can't find.

I think I need to use some kind of variable string within `<div className={????}>` but I've tried various template literal strings and none of them have worked.  What should I be doing?

Comment: Insteasd of `className={classes.innerClassName}`, maybe you can try `className={classes[innerClassName]}>`. I believe the square brackets will help with dynamic interpretation of object attribute in JS